# Le paso al input un valor o "value" de forma dinámica pero quiero editarlo que debo hacer?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Lo que quiero es hacer es un contador, que dependiendo de si pulso + me sume, que dependiendo de si pulso - pues me reste, eso ya lo hice, pero como esta dentro de un input quiero editar ese valor que lleve, y no puedo editarlo.

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  const [cantidad, setCantidad] = useState(1);

  const sumar = () => {
    setCantidad(cantidad + 1);
  };
  const restar = () => {
    setCantidad(cantidad - 1);
  };


<button style={Mystyle.btn} onClick={restar}>
  -
</button>
<input
    className="text-center"
    type="number"
    style={Mystyle.input}
    value={cantidad}
    
    />

<button style={Mystyle.btn} onClick={sumar}>
 +
</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La problemática que planteas se puede solucionar agregando el evento **onChange** del elemento input, a ese evento le podrías pasar una función que se encargue de modificar el state de tu componente, en este caso tu contador.

Quedaria algo asi:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [cantidad, setCantidad] = React.useState(1);

  const sumar = () => {
    setCantidad((cantidad) => cantidad + 1);
  };
  const restar = () => {
    setCantidad((cantidad) => cantidad - 1);
  };

  const onChangeValue = (e) => {
    setCantidad((cantidad) => parseInt(e.target.value));
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={restar}>-</button>
      <input
        className="text-center"
        type="number"
        value={cantidad}
        onChange={onChangeValue}
      />

      <button onClick={sumar}>+</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @JesusOchoa saludos.

Comment: @MairaAlejandraQuintero Si la solución propuesta propuesta te sirvió, entonces aceptala y votala para arriba. Al mismo tiempo esto le indica a otros usuarios de que es una respuesta válida para el problema que planteaste.